# mac osx, run external jar with output

Tags: java

I'm trying to run a external jar in mac osx, I want the output of it and set a property

My code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
System.setProperty("user.home", file1);
Console.Out(System.getProperty("user.home"));
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("java");
args.add("-jar");
args.add(jarFile);
pb.command(args);
Process p = pb.start();
System.setProperty("user.home", ModMaker.Root + "/MCP/jars");
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
        .getInputStream()));
while(bf.readLine() != null)
    ;
if(!new File(somedir).exists()) {
    int result = Joptionpane.showConfirmDialog(Gui.getFrame(),
            "Program isn't installed properly!\n\nRun It again?",
            "Not installed!", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if(result == 0) {
        runAgain();
    }
}
```

But when I run this, the bf.readLine is immediately null, and it say that it is stopped. But it isnt. And the Property isnt changed in the external process.

EDIT: when I run this in windows it work normal!

Comment: Try adding `jarFile.getAbsoulutePath()` instead of `jarFile` to your args.

Comment: That isnt the problem, because it run the jar, but I dont get an outputstream

Comment: You don't expect an external program to change your system property, do you? Or even **observe** it, for that matter? Another thing, how do you know that `readLine` is *immediately* null?

Comment: I'd avoid the BufferedReader in this context and rely on the InputStraem directly, there's no guarantee that the process will output any new line characters (obviously in your case, your case, you're controlling that, but is a habit worth forming)

Comment: You're also ignoring any exit value returned from process, which might provide you with more information

Comment: Its non of that, I just look like I started a process that started the jar, and finished, while the jar is still running.

Comment: Quite apart from the problems you're having, you know it's a really bad idea to modify the `user.home` system property, right?